# How to get the result using Pepin's test

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

How do I achieve this result via Pepin's test by using Euler's Theorem and such to simplify $3^{2^{31}}$ and get the desired congruence of 10,324,303?

$3^{(F_5-1)/2} = 3^{2^{31}} = 3^{2,146,483,648} \equiv 10,324,303 ≢ -1 (mod 4,294,967,297)$

Where $F_5$ is Fermat's 6th number $2^{32}+1$

Using powermod functions gives the desired result for $a^{b} mod(m)$ but I'd like to do this one by hand to better understand how powermod simplifies.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you really want to calculate it '**by hand**'??
What is the *real* question you want to ask?

Comment: If you want to use Euler's Theorem, you will need the factorization of $F_5$ in order to find $\varphi(F_5)$. The factorization is known, but rather goes against the spirit of Pepin's Test.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, working modulo $4,294,967,297$ is very difficult by hand and unwieldy even for a pocket calculator.

Secondly, the exponent $2,147,483,648$ has only one $1$ when written in binary, which does not lend itself to giving you an enlightening experience of binary exponentiation.

If you really want to try this, start by computing $3^{16}$ which is quite small. Then square the result and reduce modulo $4,294,967,297$. And repeat $26$ times until you reach $3^{2^{31}}$.